# Issue of using e.target.value in React setState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experiencing a strange issue in React. I think probably I have not fully grasped how React works and I really appreciate your help.

Please find below my React component:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  updateValue = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <form>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.updateValue} defaultValue={this.state.value} />
     </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Then, now if I type something in the text field, I will get following warning and errors:

***Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().***

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null***

But if I change the 'updateValue' method to:

```
updateValue = e => {
    const newValue = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    })
  }
```

It will work without any issue.

Comment: I don't believe the change you provided as a "solution" would make any difference, it's impossible for them to behave differently.

Comment: [I put the code in a sandbox, and I'm not seeing any such warnings in the console.](https://codesandbox.io/s/32qrq08w61) Could you update your example code to better fit your actual code?

Comment: The code you posted cannot result in that error.

Comment: this is just crazy. i just had to change my method as arrow function to get it to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated answer**

As @FelixKling pointed out, my answer wasn't entirely correct. My answer is only valid if you pass a *function* as a parameter to `setState`, not if you pass an *object* like done in the question.

If you pass an *object* to `setState`, the parameter will be evaluated immediately, that is, before the event has been nullified. As such, the mentioned error won't occur.

If you pass a *function* to `setState`, the parameter will be evaluated within that function, which happens after `updateValue` has completed/returned and the event has been nullified. If you pass a function to `setState`, you must store the `e.target.value` in a variable (or call `e.persist()`) before `setState`.

**Old (slightly wrong) answer**

This problem occurs because (as the error message says) the event is set to null when the callback (your `updateValue` function) is completed.

Because [`this.setState()` is an asynchronous function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), it will not be executed immediately. As a result, `this.setState()` is actually executed after your `updateValue` is finished, and hence after the event has been nullified.

Your solution is actually [the proposed way from the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)!

Comment: That's not quite right. `this.setState` is executed immediately. Every function that is called is executed right away. However, the state change is not applied immediately. But that has nothing to do with the error the OP sees. Function arguments are always evaluated immediately. `e.target.value` is evaluated the moment that `updateValue` is called.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, function arguments are evaluated immediately. I tested the code in the question in Codepen and saw no error. If I pass a function instead of an object to `setState` the error occurs. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

Basically, the click event (`e`) is not accessible inside the asynchronous `setState()` due to React's Event Pooling, unless you use `event.persist()` (as mentioned in the warning you received).

**React Event Pooling:** https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the way to make work this. Here a snipped.

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
  }
  updateValue(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    return ( <form>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
        onChange={this.updateValue} 
        defaultValue={this.state.value} />
      <h4>Controlled Input:</h4> <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </form>
    ); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On functional components

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

<input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
```