# Creating a relationship(OnetToMany) between 2 objects in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, spring-boot

I have a database created in MYSQL that has two tables(Patient,Caregiver) that are connected with OneToMany mapping in spring boot. I want to create a Patient Object in react Js in front end( but I would need to specify the caregiver at the moment of creation) and then send it to backend, my only issue is that i am not certain how to create the connection.

I have tried to create a select option for the caregiver reference from patient in order to chose from the caregiver-list. But I am unable to do so having gotten the error:  ##
TypeError: Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference##

My caregiver and patient entities in spring boot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient", schema = "mydbps")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idPatient", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int idPatient;

    @Column(name = "patientName")
    private String patientName;

    @Column(name = "patientSurname")
    private String patientSurname;

    @Column(name = "patientGender")
    private String patientGender;

    @Column(name = "patientBirthdate")
    private Date patientBirthdate;

    @Column(name = "patientAddress")
    private String patientAddress;

    @Column(name = "patientEmail")
    private String patientEmail;

    @Column(name = "patientPassword")
    private String patientPassword;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Caregiver_idCaregiver")
    Caregiver Caregiver_idCaregiver;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Caregiver",schema="mydbps")
public class Caregiver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCaregiver", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private int idCaregiver;

    @Column(name="caregiverName")
    private String caregiverName;

    @Column(name="caregiverSurname")
    private String caregiverSurname;

    @Column(name="caregiverGender")
    private String caregiverGender;

    @Column(name="caregiverAddress")
    private String caregiverAddress;

    @Column(name="caregiverBirthdate")
    private String caregiverBirthdate;

    @Column(name="caregiverEmail")
    private String caregiverEmail;

    @Column(name="caregiverPassword")
    private String caregiverPassword;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Caregiver_idCaregiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Patient> patientList;}
```

The contrellers:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/caregivers")
public class CaregiverController {
    @Autowired
    private CaregiverService docService;

    @PostMapping
    public ApiResponse<Caregiver> saveUser(@RequestBody CaregiverDTO user){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Caregiver saved successfully.",docService.insert(user));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ApiResponse<List<Caregiver>> listUser(){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Caregivers list fetched successfully.",docService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<Caregiver> getOne(@PathVariable int id){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Caregiver fetched successfully.",docService.findCaregiverByIdCaregiver(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<CaregiverDTO> update(@RequestBody CaregiverDTO userDto) {
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Caregiver updated successfully.",docService.update(userDto));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        docService.deleteUser(docService.findCaregiverByIdCaregiver(id));
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Caregiver deleted successfully.", null);
    }


@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients")
public class PatientController {


    @Autowired
    private PatientService docService;

    @PostMapping
    public ApiResponse<Patient> saveUser(@RequestBody PatientDTO user){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "User saved successfully.",docService.insert(user));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ApiResponse<List<Patient>> listUser(){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "User list fetched successfully.",docService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<Patient> getOne(@PathVariable int id){
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "User fetched successfully.",docService.findPatientByIdPatient(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<PatientDTO> update(@RequestBody PatientDTO userDto) {
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "User updated successfully.",docService.update(userDto));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        docService.deleteUser(docService.findPatientByIdPatient(id));
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "User deleted successfully.", null);
    }




}
```

The react js add-patient component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PatientApiService from "../../service/PatientApiService";
import CaregiverApiService from "../../service/CaregiverApiService";
import Select from 'react-select';

class AddPatientComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            patientName: '',
            patientSurname: '',
            patientEmail: '',
            patientPassword: '',
            patientGender: '',
            patientAddress: '',
            Caregiver_idCaregiver: '',
            caregivers: [],
            message: null
        }
        this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
    }

  componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadCaregiverList();

    }
  reloadCaregiverList() {
            PatientApiService.fetchCaregivers()
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({caregivers: res.data.result})
                });
        }

    saveUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let user = {patientName: this.state.patientName, patientSurname: this.state.patientSurname, patientEmail: this.state.patientEmail, patientPassword: this.state.patientPassword, patientGender: this.state.patientGender, patientAddress: this.state.patientAddress,Caregiver_idCaregiver :this.state.Caregiver_idCaregiver};
        PatientApiService.addUser(user)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message : 'Patient added successfully.'});
                this.props.history.push('/patients');
            });
    }

    onChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Add User</h2>
                <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="patientName" name="patientName" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientName} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Surname:</label>
                    <input type="patientSurname" placeholder="patientSurname" name="patientSurname" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientSurname} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Email" name="patientEmail" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientEmail} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Password" name="patientPassword" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientPassword} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Gender:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Gender" name="patientGender" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientGender} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Address:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Address" name="patientAddress" className="form-control" value={this.state.patientAddress} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

             <div className="form-group">
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-4"></div>
                   <div className="col-md-4">
                   <label>Caregiver:</label>
                    <Select options={ this.state.caregivers } name="Caregiver_idCaregiver"  value={this.state.Caregiver_idCaregiver} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({ Caregiver_idCaregiver:e.value})} />

                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-4"></div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveUser}>Save</button>
            </form>
    </div>
     <div>
                                <h2 className="text-center">Caregiver Details</h2>
                                <table className="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th className="hidden">Id</th>
                                            <th>FirstName</th>
                                            <th>LastName</th>
                                            <th>caregiverEmail</th>
                                            <th>caregiverGender</th>
                                            <th>caregiverAddress</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {
                                            this.state.caregivers.map(
                                        caregiver =>
                                                    <tr key={caregiver.idCaregiver}>
                                                        <td>{caregiver.caregiverName}</td>
                                                        <td>{caregiver.caregiverSurname}</td>
                                                        <td>{caregiver.caregiverEmail}</td>
                                                        <td>{caregiver.caregiverGender}</td>
                                                        <td>{caregiver.caregiverAddress}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            )
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddPatientComponent;
```

ApiPatient service:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const USER_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/patients';
const CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL='http://localhost:8080/caregivers';
class PatientApiService {

    fetchUsers() {
        return axios.get(USER_API_BASE_URL);
    }

    fetchUserById(userId) {
        return axios.get(USER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + userId);
    }

    deleteUser(userId) {
        return axios.delete(USER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + userId);
    }

    addUser(user) {
        return axios.post(""+USER_API_BASE_URL, user);
    }

    editUser(user) {
        return axios.put(USER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + user.id, user);
    }
    fetchCaregivers()
    {return axios.get(CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL);}

}

export default new PatientApiService();
```

My postman get service response for the fetchCaregivers is :

```
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Caregivers list fetched successfully.",
    "result": [
        {
            "idCaregiver": 1,
            "caregiverName": "Marius",
            "caregiverSurname": "Ioan",
            "caregiverGender": null,
            "caregiverAddress": null,
            "caregiverBirthdate": null,
            "patientList": []
        }
    ]
}
```

But it won't appear in the dropdown.

I wish to select the caregiver from a dropdown list but I does not apppear, also the error  which appears at runtime is :

```
×
TypeError: Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference
onChange
D:/AN 4/react-js-example-master/src/component/patient/AddPatientComponent.jsx:46
  43 | }
  44 | 
  45 | onChange = (e) =>
> 46 |     this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
     | ^
  47 | 
  48 | render() {
  49 |     return(
```

Thank you!

Comment: Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256318/issue-of-using-e-target-value-in-react-setstate-function

Comment: Could you please clarify? How will that return my names for the caregivers in the select drop-down and link the selected caregiver with the newly created patient ?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your React-Select options is an array of objects and contains, at minimum, a value and label property for each option, like so:

```
    [
        {value:'value1', label:'label1', otherProperty:'otherProperty1'},
        {value:'value2', label:'label2', otherProperty:'otherProperty2'}
    ]
```

To do so (assuming that `PatientApiService.fetchCaregivers()` returns an array of caregivers) create a renderOptions method:

```
renderOptions=(options)=>{
    return options.map(option=>{
        return {value: option.idCaregiver , label:option.caregiverName}
    })
}
```

Next keep in mind: "React-Select" does not return a typical event object such as:

```
{target:{value:'value' , label:'label' , name:'name'}}
```

Instead it returns whatever you passed in as an option to the options prop such as:

```
{value:'value' , label:'label'}
```

Therefore, accessing e.target will result in undefined, furthermore, if you try to access e.target.name you will get an error as you cannot access .name of undefined.

Additionally you also will not be able to directly extract the name of the field (as that is not a property of the react-select return object) unless you pass it explicitly in the options such as:

```
{value:'value1', label:'label1' , name:'someFieldName' , otherProperty:'otherProperty'}
```

If you don't want to change to a normal select tag then you will need to:

1. Modify the onChange for the react-select component to be the same format as your other onChange events
2. Use the renderOptions method from above
3. Remove the value prop as react-select tracks that for you

Updated select should now be:

```
<Select 
    name="Caregiver_idCaregiver"//not stricly necessary 
    options={ this.formatOptions(this.state.caregivers) } 
    onChange={(e)=>this.onChange({target:{...e , name:'Caregiver_idCaregiver'}})}
/>
```

**ADDITIONALLY**

Your `PatientApiService` does not have a method `saveUser` that you are calling in your `AddPatientComponent`'s `saveUser` method you will need to change that to match either the `editUser` or `addUser` method you have defined in your `PatientApiService`

For example to add a user:

```
saveUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let user = {patientName: this.state.patientName, patientSurname: this.state.patientSurname, patientEmail: this.state.patientEmail, patientPassword: this.state.patientPassword, patientGender: this.state.patientGender, patientAddress: this.state.patientAddress,Caregiver_idCaregiver :this.state.Caregiver_idCaregiver};
    PatientApiService.addUser(user)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({message : 'Patient added successfully.'});
            this.props.history.push('/patients');
        });
}
```

Simplified working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Select from 'react-select';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    state={
        caregivers:[ { idCaregiver: '1', caregiverName: 'User1', otherData:'data1'}, { idCaregiver: '2', caregiverName: 'User2', otherData:'data2' },],
        Caregiver_idCaregiver:''
    }

    saveUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const user = {Caregiver_idCaregiver : this.state.Caregiver_idCaregiver};
        const foundCaregiverObj = this.state.caregivers.find(caregiver=> caregiver.idCaregiver === this.state.Caregiver_idCaregiver)

        console.log(user)
        console.log(foundCaregiverObj)
    }

    onChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    renderOptions=(options)=>{
        return options.map(option=>{
            return {value: option.idCaregiver , label:option.caregiverName}
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <label>Caregiver:</label>
                <Select options={ this.renderOptions(this.state.caregivers) } name="Caregiver_idCaregiver"  onChange={(e)=>this.onChange({target:{...e , name:'Caregiver_idCaregiver'}})}/>
                <button onClick={this.saveUser}>Save</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SomeComponent />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: So, react-select does not return the choice from drop-down as a caregiver object?

Comment: It does make more sense however it does not solve the problem. I am getting "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'saveUser'"and I still can not see the name of choice in the dropdown

Comment: Updated the code but it still sends a null object reference for  Caregiver_idCaregiver.

Comment: Try to console.log(this.state.caregivers) above your return in AddPatientComponent to make sure your passing in the options correctly (see answer for correct format)

Comment: If you are properly formatted try console.log-ing your Select callback onChange={(e)=>console.log(e)}

Comment: This is the answer for console.log [object Array]: [Object]

[object Object]: {caregiverAddress: null, caregiverBirthdate: null, caregiverGender: null, caregiverName: "Marius", caregiverSurname: "Ioan"...}
caregiverAddress: null
caregiverBirthdate: null
caregiverGender: null
caregiverName: "Marius"
caregiverSurname: "Ioan"
idCaregiver: 1

patientList: Array

__proto__: Object

Comment: The issue i have now is with passing the data(a caregiver object(Caregiver_idCaregiver)  inside the pacient object) to the backend.This object is passed as a null from front-end.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear and included a full simplified example. Notice the console logs that show both the user that you are building from state as well as caregiver with the same id from the this.state.caregivers array of caregivers

Comment: Your example is not helpful or maybe i just don't understand how it can help me to send only a part of my caregiver entity( I need all of it).In addition, I have changed upon sugestion and caregiver_idCaregiver is still null when it goes to backend for processing( i need it to be an Object of type Caregiver). I need the relationship between the 2 components( that's why I have mapping OneToMany in Caregiver) which is made by setting one to the other or viceversa. In backend it would be sth like : Patient pt= new Patient(1,"name",new Caregiver(1,"nameCaregiver")).

Comment: Were you able to get my example running locally? In my example I tried to show you how to retrieve either the id or the whole caregivers object (from this.state.caregivers array). I’m sorry if I still do not understand your question. Maybe try this.... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example