# Why can't I append a child using useState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React and found something which was not quite working, but it made sense to me totally:

```js
const [Res, setRes] = useState(<div></div>);
const test = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      setRes( prevState => prevState.append(<p>{e.target.value)}</p>))
    }
  }
return(
    {Res}
)
```

If this us wrong, please tell me the correct way to solve similar problems please.

Comment: You can, you just have to wrap it inside of valid jsx

Comment: Just remember that storing components in state is not good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919014/is-it-a-good-idea-to-store-components-in-state this might be helpful

Comment: Although it might make sense to you, states should contain **data** not markup - like HTML. The render step of the components is where you declare *how* the data is rendered, not in the state. In React you stay clear of any DOM manipulation, like `append`, `getElementById`, and so forth.

Comment: @sm3sher Can you please explain? I am new to react and I can't wrap my head around this

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Then how do I append mutliple p tags to a div in react? That was the most logical solution I had but I am sorry If I am wrong

Comment: No worries. Check the provided answer below. You don't *append* p tags, you loop over the data and *render* p tags. Whenever the state changes, the data is looped over again and the rendered result should change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping JSX in state is an antipattern.

Instead of keeping the JSX in an array in state, keep the *data* in the array without JSX, then build the JSX when you are ready to render:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [res, setRes] = useState([]);

  const test = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;

    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      setRes(prev => [...prev, value]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {res.map(e => <p>{e}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`<p>` is [using index as key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), which is a problem. How to fix it is application-specific depending on where your data is coming from and whether it can be removed from the array, whether it's unique, etc, but ideally generate an id.

Also, `e.target.value` [shouldn't be accessed in a state setter callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256318/issue-of-using-e-target-value-in-react-setstate-function). It's async so the event object might have gone stale by the time it's read. Pull out the primitive value into the handler closure.

I suggest picking better names: `test` and `res` are pretty meaningless.

Finally, [instead of `e.keyCode === 13`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keycode), use [`e.code === "Enter"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

Comment: Oh got it, I push it to the empty array and print all elements of array at once. Thank you kind stranger.